# How to change table properties without changing table attributes

Tags: html, css, html-table

We are using an order management system for sending emails to customers.
This system allows us to put in "place holders" to show order related information inside the email.

For example: #?OrderItemsDetails?# gives us the following table:

```
<table><tr><td><strong>Item Name</strong></td><td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>...</tr></table>
```

The problem is, this table has no formats, like padding, margin or border-styles. The table looks ugly and is not useable.

Is it possible to use CSS for changing the look of the table inside this placeholder?

Can I put the placeholder inside a div area and change the table looks via CSS?
When I try to change the CSS for the usual table elements the whole email will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an emailer you have to play via table tags only and use inline css inside table tag like `<table border="" cellpadding="">`

Comment: The problem is, I can not edit the html I posted in the first posting. It's inside the variable which comes from the management program. Therefor I can not put class="table" inside the table tag I'd like to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: red;
}
```

You can use only table in the css but above will style your table with border and red color text. If you want some sepcific styling then you can google it but put this in your css and it should work.

Comment: The problem is, I can not edit the html I posted in the first posting. It's inside the variable which comes from the management program. Therefor I can not put class="table" inside the table tag I'd like to change.

Comment: table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: red;
}